# cast a string to a sparql URI

Tags: java, uri, sparql

I wanna simply ask if someone know a library function in java for cast a string to a SPARQL URI.
I just found org.openrdf.ValueFactory but this function need to have a connection (Repository)
how parameter and i cant do it because need to much time. I need just a function to remove special character, unicode (replace all ("\P{Print}"))...for insert the string as a URI in a SPARQL update, ask or query; something like *.string_To_URI(String string_URI);
Thanks for the time lost, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use Java URL or URI class to create the URI. It will throw you an exception if the URI is not valid.

You should check out the JENA library to create SPARQL queries. (http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html)

For example you could create a SPARQL query like this:

```
    public static String getAllTriplesOfContext(URL context) throws IOException {

            String query = new String("SELECT ?x ?y ?z \n" + "FROM ?context \n"
                            + "WHERE {?x ?y ?z}");

            ParameterizedSparqlString queryString = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
                            query);

            queryString.setIri("?context", context);

            return queryString.toString();

    }
```

Comment: org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil.encodeQuery() i think is the best method